# Image not displayed in excell cell (python and openpyxl)

Tags: python, image, resize, openpyxl

i am tring to create a script using python and openpyxl`s function called add_image which will add resized photos into cells, for this i am using the 
following code:

```
from PIL import Image
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

max_row = ws.max_row

########## SET DIMENSIONS FOR 'F' cells#######
ws.column_dimensions['F'].width=200 
for x in range (2,max_row+1):
    ws.row_dimensions[x].height=200
##############################################
img = Image.open(file)
bound_width_height = (195, 150)
img.thumbnail(bound_width_height, Image.ANTIALIAS)
nimg = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(img)
ws.add_image(nimg,'F3')

wb.save('test.xlsx')
print('done!')
```

but when i am watching into `test.xlsx` file i see `This image cannot curently be displayed.`

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4PRe.jpg

Any ideeas why?

Comment: You may need to explicitly set the image type to PNG.

Comment: @CharlieClark, still didn`t work